# TFS OData missing reference on BasicAuthToken and BasicAuthCredential

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, tfs, visual-studio-2012, odata

I am trying to set up an OData service for a company Team foundation server.  I have used a few versions but this one seems to be missing a reference that I can not locate anywhere.  The 2 classes that i seem to be missing definitions for are - `BasicAuthToken` and `BasicAuthCredential` both are throwing an error -

`The type or namespace name 'BasicAuthToken' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

`The type or namespace name 'BasicAuthCredential' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Does anyone know where these can be referenced? The Odata service can be downloaded [HERE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36230)!

Comment: Does this occur when you try to build the solution, or when you are looking at the code?

Comment: When I try to build the solution. `BasicAuthToken` And `BasicAuthCredentials` are each referenced twice.

Comment: In addition I get this warning as well which I presume is just a biproduct of the errors. `'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Proxy.StructureType' is obsolete: 'Please use Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.StructureType instead'`

Comment: `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Proxy.Structure` is not obsolete (you can find that on the MSDN site for that class), so it is not a bi-product of those two issues. I was able to download the package and build it right off. The documentation states you need to have  _Visual Studio 2012 with Update 1_ installed (optionally _Windows Azure SDK .NET_ if you want to build for the Windows Azure environment). Do you have this/these installed?

Comment: Check and check. Both VS 2012 and Azure SDK are properly installed.

Comment: Issue has been Magically resolved, I wish i could hav figured ot how it came to be fixed but there are too many variables to locate the actual fix. Thank you for your help James!

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. My solution:

On ODataTFS.Model:

1. switch the target framework to 4.5
2. replace all teamfoundation* references to version 12. The Microsoft.TeamFoundation ver 12 don't exists, remove it.
3. add Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.Integration (ver 12)
4. add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common (ver 12)

On ODataTFS.Web:

1. switch the target framework to 4.5
2. replace all teamfoundation* references to version 12.

After that you can use only the ctrl+'.' to resolve the build errors.